# How can I specify Windows Mail in AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, email, autohotkey

I'm trying to remap a couple keys for Windows Mail, but ahk_exe isn't working. I used Process Explorer to find the name of the executable. Here's my script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe HxMail.exe
f7::f9  ; Refresh
Ins::^n ; New email
#IfWinActive
```

The window's name is different depending on which account I'm using. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly try disabling (commenting out) the `#IfWinActive` (i.e., make the hotkeys global temporarily) and make sure the key remaps work as expected.  Possibly double-check the window name with Window Spy and not just PE, you can start Window Spy from the right-click menu of the tray icon of your script.  Verify the expected exe for a given window.  Verify capitalization of the exe is correct in your script.  You can also utilize `ahk_class` in many cases where you need to detect a variety of window names that are the same type of window.

Comment: Key remaps worked as expected without `#IfWinActive`. Window Spy pulled up this: `ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow
ahk_exe ApplicationFrameHost.exe`. It appears to be the same for all Universal apps.

Comment: @JJohnston2 Is there a way to check if the name of the window contains "Mail"?

Comment: #IfWinactive Mail ahk_exe ApplicationFrameworkHost.exe

Comment: No, it will only apply to universal apps with 'Mail' in the title, not all of them.  If you need to be more selective there has to be a title or class difference. One final method in lieu of that is to  check for a certain control type to be active, if the controls aren't all generic.

Comment: Gotcha, but it doesn't work. The title of the window is `Inbox - Outlook - Mail`. Could it be that the title doesn't start with Mail?

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm

Comment: Still doesn't work.